# Vue Js. How can I handle v-for data as number?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, vuejs2, vue-component

Hello I am new coding at vue.js, sorry if I can't explain myself as clearly.
I have problem with `v-for`:

```html
<img :src="i.images.480w_still.url" />
```

I'm using Giphy api to search gifs and I get a response of so many images. I want to use the resized as 480w version and list them all, but when I get this response `data.data`, I can't use the `480w_still` object:

```js
.then((res) => {
   this.list = res.data.data;
   console.log(this.list);})`
```

The console representation of the object:

[image: pushing to list array and showing console.log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, variable names can't begin with a number.  Object properties can, but in that case you can't use dot notation to access them.  So that means you'll have to use bracket notation to access this property `480w_still`:

```html
<img :src="i.images['480w_still'].url" />
```

Bracket notation allows you to access property names that wouldn't be valid variable names.

Answer (score -1):

Hi redrodawn probably you are facing problems trying to get this property **480w_still** because the only way you can get a property with especial characters is using this syntax :  i.images['480w_still'].url  although i recommend you to use maps instead.
this is an example i've just made using giphy's api
you just need to add your own api key

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    categories: []
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getGiphyTrends()
  },
  methods: {
    getGiphyTrends() {
       axios.get('https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/categories?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY&limit=5').then(({data}) => {
      this.categories = data.data.map(category => ({name: category.name, images: category.gif.images['480w_still']}))  
       } );
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="category in categories" >
    <h2>{{category.name}}</h2>
    <img v-for="(image, index) in category.images" :key="index" :src="image" />
  </div>
</div>
```